# Can the creator of a Facebook group be removed?

Tags: facebook-groups

Is there a way for all the references to the creator of a Facebook group to be removed? Or for the group to be taken away from the creator without their permission?

A friend of mine is an Admin for a group where they want to remove the creator's name from the group. The original creator is not available to leave the group and from what I've read, even then they'd still be listed as the original creator. The other admins for the group want it to appear as if someone else created the group in the first place. Is there a way to do this through FB or do I need to contact a human at Facebook and get them to intervene?